# Just this last inequality

Tags: calculus, inequality

I can't seem to find a counterexample to disprove it:
$\sqrt{k}k^c + (2\sqrt{k+1}-1)\dfrac{\sqrt{k^k}}{2^{k-1}} -\sqrt{k+1}(k+1)^c≤0$.

For $k \ge 1, c>0$ both real

Comment: @jjnchurliki You should use LaTex for arranging your formulas, and the titles of your questions should be more descriptive. Consider visiting http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help to learn how to format your questions appropriately.

Comment: Try with $k=3, c=1$

Answer (score 3):

For $k=1$ and $c=0.5$ you get $$1 + (2 \sqrt{2} - 1) \cdot 1 - \sqrt{2}2^{0.5} > 0$$

Comment: @jinchuriki I don't know your culture but I don't find using sexy very appropriate in any semi-formal context.

Answer (score 1):

Let $k=2$ and $c=.1$. Then

$$\sqrt2\cdot2^{.1}+(2\sqrt{2+1}-1)\frac{\sqrt{2^2}}{2^{2-1}}-\sqrt{2+1}\cdot(2+1)^{.1}$$

which you can compute easily (and accurate enough) with modern calculators, and see that it is larger than $0$ (in fact, it is around $2.0466...$).

Comment: it is nice and cool

Comment: @vrugtehagel Apparently, you meant $k=2$.

Comment: Yes. That was a silly typo, thanks for correcting me!

Answer (score 1):

This is also a rather easy problem.

Plugging $k=1$ in and after a few easy lines then we have:

$$
2 \le 2^c
$$

Then for any $0<c<1$ this inequality is proved wrong.